# React validation as well as clearing input

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am trying to figure out the best way to run my validation for react. Right now when I submit the registration is successful but all the validation throws an error because I clear the inputs after it submits.

What is the best way for me to still validate and clear the inputs once the form successfully submits.

How can I either clear the inputs in my `function register(user)` so that they are not blank at submission or fix the validation to not throw errors once the form submits if there was the correct information entered?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { userActions } from '../_actions';

class RegisterPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            user: {
                firstName: '',
                lastName: '',
                username: '',
                password: ''
            },
            submitted: false
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        const { user } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            user: {
                ...user,
                [name]: value
            }
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({ submitted: true,
       user: {
         firstName: '',
         lastName: '',
         username: '',
         password: ''
       }
     });
        const { user } = this.state;
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        if (user.firstName && user.lastName && user.username && user.password) {
            dispatch(userActions.register(user));
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { registering  } = this.props;
        const { user, submitted } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h2>Register</h2>
                <form name="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.firstName ? ' has-error' : '')}>
                        <label htmlFor="firstName">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="firstName" value={user.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        {submitted && !user.firstName &&
                            <div className="help-block">First Name is required</div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.lastName ? ' has-error' : '')}>
                        <label htmlFor="lastName">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" className="form-control" name="lastName" value={user.lastName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        {submitted && !user.lastName &&
                            <div className="help-block">Last Name is required</div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.username ? ' has-error' : '')}>
                        <input type="hidden" className="form-control" name="username" value={user.username = user.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        {submitted && !user.username &&
                            <div className="help-block">Username is required</div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.password ? ' has-error' : '')}>
                        <input type="hidden" className="form-control" name="password" value={user.password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        {submitted && !user.password &&
                            <div className="help-block">Password is required</div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <button className="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                        {registering &&
                            <img src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
                        }
                      {/*  <Link to="/login" className="btn btn-link">Cancel</Link> */}
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { registering } = state.registration;
    return {
        registering
    };
}

const connectedRegisterPage = connect(mapStateToProps)(RegisterPage);
export { connectedRegisterPage as RegisterPage };
```

user actions

```
function register(user) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(request(user));

        userService.register(user)
            .then(
                user => {
                    dispatch(success());
                  {/*  history.push('/register'); */}
                    dispatch(alertActions.success('Registration successful'));
                },
                error => {
                    dispatch(failure(error));
                    dispatch(alertActions.error(error));
                }
            );
    };

    function request(user) { return { type: userConstants.REGISTER_REQUEST, user } }
    function success(user) { return { type: userConstants.REGISTER_SUCCESS, user } }
    function failure(error) { return { type: userConstants.REGISTER_FAILURE, error } }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick simplified example:

```
class RegisterPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: {
        value: '',
          error: true
        },
        password: {
          value: '',
          error: true
        }
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    let error = false;

    if (!value) {
      error = true
    }

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      [name]: {
        value,
        error
      }
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log("Dispatching action");
  }

  render() {
    const { registering  } = this.props;
    const { username, password} = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Register</h2>
            <form name="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" value={username.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    {username.error &&
                        <div>First Name is required</div>
                    }
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" value={password.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    {password.error &&
                        <div>Last Name is required</div>
                    }
                    <button disabled={username.error || password.error}>Register</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In this case I disable the button so it can't even be submitted unless there are no errors.

Keep in mind this is just one example and there is no RIGHT way to do this. It's up to you as to how exactly you want to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

I think The first thing what you should do is to remove all logic from render return. Basically right now you have the validation in the divs by adding has-error classes conditionally. Remove those, and instead move the validation errors into the state, next to every field. Something like this:

```
user: {
         firstName: {
            value: '',
            error: ''
         },
         lastName: '',
         username: '',
         password: ''
       }
```

Also you should have some kind of validation rule mapping, where you config that which field have to apply which rule ( like required, number etc. ) In the ideal world this should be a different general service, which is reusable in your next form also. Think about it like you have a Validation Service, You have your rule set, and you have your State. Then you just gave the state with the rules to the validation service which gives back a new state, where all the fields are validated ( the error part is filled ). An extra state parameter would be nice too which tells about your whole state is valid or not.

Allowing the form submission will be based on your whole valid state, so if the state is invalid you submit button can be disabled, so the handle submit cannot be called. So in the moment when the submit happens you dont have to care about your validation anymore.

Also as far as I see you are clearing your state before reading out the data. Invert the logic. Create a seperate function which resets the state, on form submition read out the data, reset the form then call the register. Should be fine.

Comment: is there any chance you can use my code and give me an example of how I should do it so I can figure it out. I am pretty new to react